# Problem while posting data in spring boot Rest Api- org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I am new to spring boot rest api.
I have create a category Rest controller using which i am posting data to my backend mysql database.

I also added spring-jpa and hibernate in my project and its working fine.
When I am posting data using Bootstrap form and JqueryAjax, i am gettting org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException in intellij console and 400 in browser console when i am hitting submit button in my form.

my rest cotroller code

```
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    //@GetMapping("/Categories")
    @RequestMapping(value="/Categories", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<Category> getAllCategories(Pageable pageable) {
        return categoryRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }


    //@PostMapping("/Categories")
    @RequestMapping(value="/Categories", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public Category createCategory( @Valid @RequestBody Category Category) {
        return categoryRepository.save(Category);
    }
```

my js-ajax file

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {

        // SUBMIT FORM
        $("#Cateform").submit(function(event) {
            // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
            event.preventDefault();
            ajaxPost();
        });

        function ajaxPost() {
            // PREPARE FORM DATA
            var formData = {

                CategoryId : $("#CatId").val(),
                CategoryName : $("#CatName").val(),
                CategoryDescription : $("#Catdesc").val()
            }

            // DO POST
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                contentType : "application/json",
                url : "http://localhost:8080/Categories",
                data : JSON.stringify(formData),
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(result) {
                    if (result.status == "success") {
                        $("#postResultDiv").html(
                            "" + result.data.CategoryName
                               + result.data.CategoryDescription
                            + "Post Successfully! <br>"
                            + "---> Congrats !!" + "</p>");
                    } else {
                        $("#postResultDiv").html("<strong>Error</strong>");
                    }
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    alert("Error!")
                    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                }
            });

        }
    })
```

My Bootstrap form

```
<form id="Cateform">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="CatId" placeholder="Enter Book Id" name="CategoryId">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="CatName">Category Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CatName"  name="CategoryName">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Catdesc">Category Desc:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Catdesc"  name="CategoryDescription">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

my category model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Categories")
public class Category extends AuditingModel {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer categoryId;
    public String CategoryName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 250)
    public String Description;


 //gettter and setters
}
```

The good thing is that...i am able to post data using swagger-UI and PostMan but i dont know what is happeing when i am posting data using form and getting method argument not valid exception for the my description field of category model. 
i have set this field as notnull in model but why its giving error from posting the data from UI and not from Swagger-UI and Postman.

below is the exxact error i get in intellij console when i am hitting submit in form

**
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public edu.ait.shoppingCart.Dto.Category edu.ait.shoppingCart.Controllers.CategoryController.createCategory(edu.ait.shoppingCart.Dto.Category): [Field error in object 'category' on field 'Description': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.category.Description,NotNull.Description,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [category.Description,Description]; arguments []; default message [Description]]; default message [must not be null]] ]
**
[browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUw1H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the problem is variable name miss match. The ajax call sends the CategoryDescription while the entity expects Description also note the case sensitive C on categoryId. Ajax call sends a capital C while the entity was declared with a small letter c